# Laravel - How to get difference between two dates on change in Laravel and load result into textbox

Tags: jquery, laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 Leave Project, I have this Model Class:

```
protected $table = 'hr_leave_requests';
protected $fillable = [
              'id',
              'reason',
              'leave_type_id',
              'commencement_date',
              'resumption_date',
              'no_of_days',
              'relief_officer_id',
          ];
```

Already I can successfully save data into the database
Controller

```
public function store(StoreLeaveRequestRequest $request)
{
try {   
        $commencementDate   = Carbon::parse($request->commencement_date);
        $resumptionDate     = Carbon::parse($request->resumption_date);
        $leaverequest = HrLeaveRequest::create([
            'leave_type_id'             => $request->leave_type_id,
            'commencement_date'         => $commencementDate,
            'resumption_date'           => $resumptionDate,               
            'reason'                    => $request->reason,
        ]);
        Session::flash('success', 'Leave Request is created successfully');
        return redirect()->route('service.leave_requests.index');
    } 
    catch (Exception $exception) 
    {
        Session::flash('error', 'Action failed!');
        return redirect()->route('service.leave_requests.index');  
    }        
}
```

View

```
<form  action="{{route('service.leave_requests.store')}}" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       {{csrf_field()}}
       <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-body">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Leave Type:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                <select class="form-control select2bs4" data-placeholder="Choose Leave Type" tabindex="1" name="leave_type_id" style="width: 100%;">>
                    <option value="">Select Leave Type</option>
                    @if($leavetypes->count() > 0)
                        @foreach($leavetypes as $leavetype)
                            <option value="{{$leavetype->id}}">{{$leavetype->leave_type_name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    @endif
                </select>
            </div>
          </div>  

          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Commencement Date:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="commencement_date" value="{{old('commencement_date')}}"  min="{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->firstOfYear()->format('Y-m-d')}}" max="{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->lastOfYear()->format('Y-m-d')}}">
            </div>
          </div>                    
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Resumption Date:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="resumption_date" value="{{old('resumption_date')}}"  min="{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->firstOfYear()->format('Y-m-d')}}" max="{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->lastOfYear()->format('Y-m-d')}}">
            </div>
          </div> 
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Leave Days:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                <input  type="number" name="no_of_days" class="form-control" value="{{old('no_of_days')}}" style="width: 100%;" disabled>
            </div>
          </div>                


          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Reason</label>
                <textarea rows="2" name="reason" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Reason here" value="{{old('reason')}}"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>                

       </div>
     </div>
    </div>          
    <!-- /.card-body -->
    <div class="card-footer">
            <button type="submit" id="submit_create" class="btn btn-primary">{{ trans('global.save') }}</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='{{route('service.leave_requests.index')}}'" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
    </div>           

 </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(function () {
            $('#commencement_date').datetimepicker({
                format: "YYYY-MM-DD"
            });
            $('#resumption_date').datetimepicker({
                format: "YYYY-MM-DD"
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

What I want to achieve is that resumption_date onchange should calculate the difference between commencement_date and resumption_date and load the result as integer into no_of_days.

How do I achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `diffInDays`

```
$no_of_days = $resumptionDate->diffInDays(commencementDate)
```

Comment: Will it automatically convert $no_of_days to integer